# New RV refrigerator sat outside in hot weather

Tags: refrigerator

I purchased an RV Dometic refrigerator.  Before it was delivered, it sat outside for 48 hours in over 100 degree temperatures each day.  There was no packaging around the refrigerator.  Should I return it?

Answer (score 1):

I would saw NO as an answer.
Why would you return a perfectly good refrigerator? The operating temps inside the compressor while running far exceed 100 degrees.

I know my RV when sitting in the sun the inside temps go beyond 100 if I forget to turn on the solar vent (a fan that is solar powered drawing in cool air pushing hot out).